# How to connect to Ethereum Blockchain without using Metamask?

Tags: go-ethereum

Is there any direct way to interact with Blockchain?
I don't want any intermediary like Metamask.

Answer (score 1):

#### Running your own node:

You can interact with the blockchain by running your own node. You can install and sync Mist, Parity, Ethereum Wallet all of which will allow you to access the blockchain via the UI of a browser ( which I'm assuming you would be more comfortable with ).

- https://ethcore.io/parity.html
- https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases

---

#### Broadcasting to the network:

You can also broadcast signed transactions to the network without a node, but you will need to rely on a third party doing that for you.

Basically if you do not want an intermediary between you and the network then the only way to do this is to have your own node.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to interact with dapps or directly with addresses and contracts.

1. To interact with dapps, you can use mist browser but you can also plug your metamask plugin to your own ethereum node. In this case, everything is under your control.
2. Interacting with addresses or contracts can be done using your own node running geth or parity for the most widely used implementations. But you can also use a friendly overlay like myetherwallet that can be plugged to you own node too and you then also have full control.